# How to share video with linkedin api in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, video, linkedin-api

I am dealing with a social media management project. In this project, I connect to the linkedin api and share a post on the linkedin page. I took care of text, image sharing. But I'm stuck with the video sharing process.

I want to share video on linkedin page with linkedin api. I'm trying to upload a video before, but I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:organization:12341234",
    "processingFailureReason": "CORRUPTED_ENTITY",
    "id": "urn:li:video:asd1234asd1234",
    "purpose": "VIDEO_AD",
    "status": "PROCESSING_FAILED"
}
```

My transaction codes are below. where am i doing wrong? anyone with knowledge please help..

```
  // LinkedIn API endpoint ve istek verisi
        $endpoint = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videos?action=initializeUpload';
        $data = [
            'initializeUploadRequest' => [
                'owner' => $ORGANIZATION_URN,
                'fileSizeBytes' => $byte,
                'uploadCaptions' => false,
                'uploadThumbnail' => false
            ]
        ];

        // Guzzle HTTP istemcisini oluşturma
        $client = new Client();

        // LinkedIn API'ye POST isteği gönderme
        $response = $client->post($endpoint, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken, // LinkedIn API erişim belirtecini buraya yerleştirin
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'x-li-format' => 'json'
            ],
            'json' => $data
        ]);

        // API cevabını çözme
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        $video_urn = $responseBody['value']['video'];
        // Cevaptan gerekli verileri alma
        $uploadUrl = $responseBody['value']['uploadInstructions'][0]['uploadUrl'];
        $lastByte = $responseBody['value']['uploadInstructions'][0]['lastByte'];
        $firstByte = $responseBody['value']['uploadInstructions'][0]['firstByte'];

        // Video dosyasını açma
        $file = fopen($videoPath, 'r');
        $ids = [];
        // Parçaları 4 MB'a kadar okuma ve yükleme
        while (!feof($file)) {
            Log::info('while');
            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'Content-Range' => "bytes $firstByte-$lastByte",
            ])->post($uploadUrl);
            Log::info(json_encode($uploadUrl));

            // Bir sonraki parça için firstByte ve lastByte değerlerini güncelleme
            $firstByte = $lastByte + 1;
            $lastByte = $firstByte + 4194303;
            Log::info('if firstByte' . $firstByte);
            Log::info('if lastByte' . $lastByte);
            //var_dump($response);
            array_push($ids, $response->getHeader('ETag')[0]);
        }
        // Video dosyasını kapatma
        fclose($file);
        // LinkedIn API endpoint ve istek verisi
        $finalizeEndpoint = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videos?action=finalizeUpload';
       
        $finalizeData = [
            "finalizeUploadRequest" => [
                "video" => $video_urn,
                "uploadToken" => "",
                "uploadedPartIds" =>
                $ids

            ]
        ];  
        // LinkedIn API'ye POST isteği gönderme
        $response = Http::withToken($accessToken)->post(
            $finalizeEndpoint,
            $finalizeData
        );
        // API cevabını çözme
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        return Http::withToken($accessToken)->get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videos/' . $video_urn);
```